# How to fix Simple_DOM memory limit fatal error?

Tags: php, dom, memory, loops, limit

Anyone had any luck with fixing the Simple_DOM memory problem? I scoured these forums and found only recommmendations for other parsing engines.

My script loops through 20,000 files and extracts one word from each. I have to call the file_get_html function each time.

- Moved it to a different server. Same result.
- Changed the foreach loop to a while loop.
- increase memory limit, either server. won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can increase the memory with `ini_set()` but that's only of you have the permission to do so.
what i recommend is when you are going through your loop, when you complete the task, unset the variables that contain the large sets of data.

```
for($i=0;$i < 30000;$i++){
  $file = file_get_contents($some_path.$i);
  // do something, like write to file

  // unset the variables
  unset($file);
}
```

of course this is just an example, but you can relate it to your codeand make sure every request is like a running your file the first time.

Wish you Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the approach to processing that much data during a single execution is flawed.  In my experience, PHP cli processed aren't really meant to run for long periods of time and process tons of data.  It takes very, very careful memory management to do so.  Throw in a leaky 3rd party script, and you have a recipe for banging your head against a desk.

Maybe instead of attempting to run through all 20k files at once, you could process a few hundred at a time, store the results someplace intermediary, like a MySQL database, and then gather the results once all the files have been processed.

Comment: yeah that's the way I've ended up doing it - Also, disabling images seems to help when parsing web urls.